# C# , make method more generic

Tags: c#, generics

Please look at the following method:

```
internal IEnumerable<Query> FilterOnUserInvolvement(IEnumerable<Query> input)
{
    var user = _userManager.GetUserByADName(_user.Identity.Name);
    if (_userManager.IsUserAdministrator(user) || _userManager.IsUserStaff(user))
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        using (var context = new QAContext())
        {
            var involvedQueries = context.UserInvolvement.Where(x => x.UserID == user.ID).Select(x => x.QueryID).ToList();
            return input.Where(i => involvedQueries.Contains(i.ID));
        }
    }
}
```

Now this method takes `IEnumerable<Query>` and returns the same.

Actually the functionality of this method could be applied to any `IEnumerable<Type>` that holds ID.

How can I rewrite this query, using generics so it can be called with another Type that holds ID?

Comment: What's the type of `context.UserInvolvement`?

Comment: Are you able to change the `Query` type? For instance, add an interface to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just restrict your `T` to a type that contains `ID`:

```
internal IEnumerable<T> FilterOnUserInvolvement<T>(IEnumerable<T> input) where T : ISomeInterfaceWithId
{

}
```

Comment: Absolutely right direction but a bit more sample code would be nice ;)

Comment: what could be added to the sample?

Comment: Actually, might be worth mentioning that `where T : SomeBaseTypeWithId` works as well.

Comment: @DaveBecker I think that interface code, could be useful for some people, but I must admit, this completely unnecessary.

Comment: sorry, what is completely unnecessary?

Comment: @DaveBecker my comment was regarding your first comment, not second.

Comment: @maccettura You wrote: 'FilterOnUserInvolvement<IEnumerable<T>>' It should be 'FilterOnUserInvolvement<T>'

Comment: None the less I will accept this answer, thank you for the fast reply!